# css is not loading properly in IE 8

Tags: html, css

My stylesheet page is not working in IE 8.Styles are showing in css page.But it doesn't works well. Its works well in firefox.Here I added my code.Anybody can explain me?

```html
<html class="no-js no-touch"><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">

<title>Tasmanian Self-Drive Tour – eBook guides</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
<meta name="description" content="Imagine arriving in Tasmania and being able to start sightseeing immediately, with absolutely no effort. With either of these eBooks, you’ll have the easiest holiday you’ve ever had."><meta name="keywords" content="Tasmania, Tasmanian, selfdrive tour, self-drive tour, touring Tasmania, driving around Tasmania, Tasmania by car, sightseeing Tasmania, travelling around Tasmania, travelling with kids, tassie, tassie tour, tasmania with kids">
<!--BEGIN-STYLESHEETS-->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<link href="fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- google font css link -->

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap:400,700,400italic,700italic|Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- additional styles -->
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<link href="css/component.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<style type="text/css"></style>
<!-- Enable this css if you want to override styles-->
<!--<link href="css/override.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">-->
<!--END-OF-STYLESHEETS-->
<!-- Favicon and Apple Icons -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icons/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/icons/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/icons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="img/icons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you checked if your style is compatible with IE8 with http://caniuse.com/ ?

Comment: Here http://tassietour.com/ is my site url

Answer (score 0):

IE8 is kinda a nightmare browser, a bit less than IE7 and quite a bit more than IE9. IE has been that way ever since Microsoft "won" the browser wars (against Netscape) and put on the brakes.

What you can do for IE8: build a set of CSS rules it is happy with and add conditional comments to only make IE8 see them.

What I do usually: add rules in a file for IE8 only to work around the browser's lack of abilities and outright bugs.

e.g.:

`<!--[if IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="IE8.css"><![endif]-->`

(add that after the normal link to you stylesheet so it can overrule with the same specificity)